# Picasso context error

Tags: android, picasso

I'm using fragement actitivty ,but context error

```
Picasso.get(activity)
```

this line activity error
[image: Error Scrrenshot]

```
 public void setdetails(FragmentActivity activity, String sitename, String sitelink, final String imageuri) {
        TextView District = (TextView) mview.findViewById(R.id.txtsitename);

        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) mview.findViewById(R.id.imgsiteimage);


        Picasso.get(activity).load(imageuri).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(imageView, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                Picasso.get().load(imageuri).placeholder(R.drawable.loadbar).into(imageView);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Replace activity with context

Comment: wow,,,it's working,,thanks you,, just i remove activity,works fine

Comment: I just add an answer please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `activity` from `get()` like this.

```
Picasso.get().load(imageuri).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(imageView, new Callback()
```

This will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace activity with context like this**

```
  File file = new File(filePath);

Picasso.with(context).load(file).placeholder(R.drawable.draw_detailed_view_display).error(R.drawable.draw_detailed_view_display)
    .resize(400, 400).into(mImageView, new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {
            mImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think the OP is using the latest [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) version. It is now `get()`.